# How to make top border animated where color goes from left to right

Tags: javascript, css

I finished my idea and it works as it is, but it's static and as all developer like, we want to make it better. I have a script where user choose his own top border color for posts(self-developed forum feature).

There is forum post and top border is colored in some color. How can I make it animated. You know when there is a circle and color goes around (it can be different colors) and makes that cool effect (never ending). I don't want something complex as that. I would like a very "simple" concept. Top border color is red (example). Animation starts from left all the way to the right and then repeats. It works like a pulse when heart beats. Like some different color going in that single line, reaching end, stops, repeat.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
    var postDivs = $(".post");
    $.each(postDivs, function(index, div) {
        var color = ($(".post .postprofile-info")[index].firstChild.nextSibling.data[0] == "#") ? $(".post .postprofile-info")[index].firstChild.nextSibling.data : "#d4d4d4";
        $(this).css("border-top", "15px solid " + color);
        var element1 = $(".post .postprofile-info ")[index].firstChild;
        $(".post .postprofile-info")[index].firstChild.nextSibling.data = "";
        element1.style.visibility = "hidden";
 
    });
```

I know it's quite messy and very badly written but it works :D
Focus here on this line:

```
$(this).css("border-top", "15px solid " + color);
```

How can I animate that? I hope I managed to explain myself as best as I could. :)

Comment: It seems like you want to make your top border oscillate between 0 width and 100% width which would give the left->right->back effect. This may be a little tricky to do just with `border-top` as you can't really change it's width or give it any effect of such. 

What I would suggest is wrapping you element in another div that is the same height + 1px on the top  to give it a top border effect. Then change its width from 0 -> 100 back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the border in the way you would like on the actual element, but you can get the effect using pure CSS (without having to add extra elements to the DOM) by using a before pseudo element.

Here's a simple example in pure HTML/CSS:

```css
div {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  animation: grow 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>some info</div>
```

Comment: Yes. that's the animation I need but here is the trick. Every user has it's own color selected and I don't know which one so I can't just name it color:red. That's why I use JS to obtain the color value and according to that color top border. Your animation is good, but pseudo-elements can't be edited by JS sadly. :(

Comment: No, but you can set a CSS property using JS (or in a style attribute) and that's what you can do in this case.

Comment: I tried to do so. Maybe it's a wrong way. I set variable inside :root and used that value to change color of border-top for pseudo element. I thought I can change it with JS like this: 
`r.style.setProperty('--blue', 'lightblue');` but it didn't work.

Comment: You want a different color on different elements so you need to change the CSS variable for each of the. Nothing to do with root.

Comment: Here is the live example of different color for border top: [link](https://srpskaucionica.forumotion.com/t2-sah-kao-sport#20)

Thing is, static part works fine, but the animated part does not.

Comment: The issue is resolved. There was some issue with other classes such as online class. It's just a forum related classes. Now it works. ^^